# DateTimeFormatter.parse returns an invalid Japanese date

Tags: java, date, java-time, datetimeformatter

I'm trying to convert a Japanese date string to JapaneseDate.

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("Gyy年MM月dd日")
    .withChronology(JapaneseChronology.INSTANCE)
    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT);
JapaneseDate d = JapaneseDate.from(formatter.parse("平成01年01月01日"));
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(d.format(formatter));
```

output:

```
Japanese Reiwa 71-01-01
令和71年01月01日
```

Since "令和元年" is "2019", "令和71年01月01日" is "2089-01-01".
"平成01年01月01日" must be "1989-01-01".

How can I convert it correctly?

If I change the resolver style to `ResolverStyle.STRICT`, it throws

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '平成01年01月01日'
could not be parsed: year, month, and day not valid for Era
```

If I change the resolver style to `ResolverStyle.SMART`, it throws

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '平成01年01月01日'
could not be parsed: Invalid YearOfEra for Era: Heisei 101
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you change to `ResolverStyle.STRICT`?

Comment: @DavidConrad It throws `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '平成01年01月01日' could not be parsed: year, month, and day not valid for Era`.

Comment: @Abra I added `Locale.JAPAN` or `Locale.JAPANESE` to `.ofPattern()`. But nothing changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this pattern:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("Gy年MM月dd日")
```

---

`y` should be used single-handed otherwise it will be added a hundred years when it is up to `11` (cf. [Javaバージョン別の改元(新元号)対応まとめ](https://qiita.com/yamadamn/items/56e7370bae2ceaec55d5#date-and-time-api%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E4%BE%8B)).

year 11:

```
JapaneseDate d = JapaneseDate.from(formatter.parse("平成11年11月01日"));
```

output:

```
Japanese Reiwa 81-11-01
令和81年11月01
```

year 12:

```
JapaneseDate d = JapaneseDate.from(formatter.parse("平成12年11月01日"));
```

output:

```
Japanese Heisei 12-11-01
平成12年11月01
```